# Is there a WaitForText or WaitForElement method in Selenium 2?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I found WaitForPageToLoad,WaitForCondition and popup. I have an ajax request which is creating some new elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using this code in Java - it checks for 3 seconds (configurable) for specified element:

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, /*seconds=*/3);
    elementOfPage = wait.until(presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("id_of_element")));


 Function<WebDriver, WebElement> presenceOfElementLocated(final By locator) {
  return new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return driver.findElement(locator);
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WaitForElement.

Check http://agilesoftwaretesting.com/?p=111